# Not able to get value in Using DropDownField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I am using below `DropDownField` code to for countries listing, But I am not able to store the value in the `String selectedValue`. I am using  `DropDownField` dependency in flutter.

```
List<String> countries = [
    'FRANCE',
    'USA',
    'JAPAN',
  ];

String selectedValue;
    DropDownField( icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                  required: false,
                              hintText: 'Choose a country',
                              labelText: 'Country',
                              items: countries,
                              setter: (dynamic newValue) {
                                setState(() {

                                  selectedValue = newValue;
                                });
                              }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use onChanged to get value from DropDown.

```
 DropDownField( icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                  required: false,
                              hintText: 'Choose a country',
                              labelText: 'Country',
                              items: countries,
                              onChanged:(value){
                                   print(value)
                              }
                              }),
```